# Falha na chamada do procedimento remoto. [0x800706be]

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, servidor, sql-server-2012

Após a instalação do SQL Server 2008 R2, acesso o SQL Server Management Studio porém o server name não aparece e no SQL Server Configuration Manager os serviços não estão ativos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Estava com o mesmo problema e com a resposta do Durval Ramos consegui resolver.
Bastou atualizar para o SP3. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema está relacionado à uma atualização incompleta que não atualizou todos os componentes necessários para executar um ou mais serviços do SQL Server.

Faça a instalação do último Service Pack do SQL Server 2008 R2 para corrigir este problema.

Segue o link:
https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=44271

Para maiores informações veja:
https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/kb/2527041/pt-br